# How do I boost a potentially existing field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got some Elasticsearch indices whose mappings are unknown to me at the time of searching. I use the following to perform an AND search for the words "lorem" and "ipsum":

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "lorem AND ipsum"
        }
    }
}
```

The nice thing here is that the search is performed across all fields in the indices. Now, some indices have a field called "title" and I want to boost these to rank these more relevant. But only if they exist, of course. I've tried to play around with the parameters of the "query_string" clause, but the only way I've been able to boost the "title" field is by using the following query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields": ["title^2"],
            "query" : "lorem AND ipsum"
        }
    }
}
```

This causes the "query_string" clause to only search the "title" field and none of the other fields - and remember, I don't know what these other fields are. Using a wildcard in the "default_field" parameter will only cause an exception if used together with the "fields" parameter.

So basically I want to tell Elasticsearch to:

> Search for "lorem" and "ipsum" and rank the result higher if you find
>   them in a field called "title"

How would I go about achieving something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `function_score`

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "title",
                "factor": "2",
                "modifier": "multiply",
                "missing": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, but how would you incorporate that into the example query in my question? Could you please show the complete query?

Comment: From what I understand after trying to read up on the field_value_factor function is that it is used to boost the query by the value of a specific field, and not to boost the field itself. So this won't help, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

While "field_value_factor" was a dead end, the "function_score" led me in the right direction. This is the query I (in principle) ended up using:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "lorem AND ipsum"
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": ["name"],
                            "query": "lorem AND ipsum"
                        }
                    },
                    "weight": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It will search all fields in all indices for the words "lorem" and "ipsum" and double the score of a search hit if those words were both found in a field called "name".